# Convert JSON data to List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am facing a problem in flutter for converting JSON data as `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

```dart
rawJson =
        '[{"value":"1","label":"red"}, {"value":"2","label":"Green"}, {"value":"3","label":"Yellow"}]';
```

This data need to convert as `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

**The following code is working, but need help top things.**

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = [
    {
      'value': '1',
      'label': 'Red',
    },
    {
      'value': '2',
      'label': 'Green',
    },
    {
      'value': '3',
      'label': 'Yellow',
    },
  ];
```

Comment: i don't understand about you't question, you'r code work fine. what do you want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast your json like this:

```dart
var rawJson = '[{"value":"1","label":"red"}, {"value":"2","label":"Green"}, {"value":"3","label":"Yellow"}]';

List<Map<String, dynamic>> output = (json.decode(rawJson) as List).cast();
// or
List<Map<String, dynamic>> output = List.from(json.decode(rawJson) as List);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what your are looking for:

```
  var rawJson =
      '[{"value":"1","label":"red"}, {"value":"2","label":"Green"}, {"value":"3","label":"Yellow"}]';

  var iterableResult = (jsonDecode(rawJson) as List<dynamic>).map((element) =>
      {"value": int.parse(element['value']), "label": element['label']});
  var listResult = iterableResult.toList();
  print(listResult); // prints [{value: 1, label: red}, {value: 2, label: Green}, {value: 3, label: Yellow}]
```